# Plotting the result of a script as a graph in grafana

Tags: shell, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I have a bash script which runs on a linux server which stores the data to a csv file and send it via email. This script runs every week. The output of the script is of the format

```
12/21/2022: 300
19/12/2022: 450
```

I have promethuese server running on same server and grafana as well in a centralised server. Is there a way where I can graphically represents this csv output in grafana?

so instead of email, people can just see the graph and corelate the data ?

Promethuese is running as kubernetes pods in a seperate namespace and the shell script is running in kubernetes master node

I found a way to manually imports google sheet, but is there a way to automate it via script where I can push the results directly to promethuese server and then use promethuese as a datasource in grafana and create dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a couple of different ways:

- If produced csv file is reachable form Grafana (it's not quite clear you are speaking about your own centalized server or grafana.com in question) you could use [CSV plugin](https://grafana.github.io/grafana-csv-datasource/). This way Grafana could query data for visualization straight from csv, no additional steps.
- If host where script is run has node_exporter and it is possible to change format of output of the script: change output format to [Pormetheus' text-based metris](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) and enable [textfile collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector) in node_exporter.
- If host has not node_exporter, but changing of script feasible you could use [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) to push metrics into Prometheus.
- If all other routes not available, you always could write your own exporter and expose/push parsed from CSV (by very same exporter) metrics.